# How to measure the Height of a Hyperlink element?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, hyperlink, flowdocument

I want to create simple "lazy loading tooltips" for Hyperlinks in a WPF RichTextBox.

I do this with a Popup control, like this:

```
    private Popup popup;
    private void Hyperlink_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Hyperlink hyper = sender as Hyperlink;
        popup = new Popup();
        popup.Child = new Label() { Content = "content of the popup" };
        popup.IsOpen = true;
        var pos = e.GetPosition(richTextBox);
        popup.Placement = PlacementMode.RelativePoint;
        popup.PlacementTarget = richTextBox;
        popup.HorizontalOffset = pos.X;
        popup.VerticalOffset = pos.Y + 30;
    }
```

To achieve this, I have to measure the Height (in pixels) of a given Hyperlink element, so I can replace this "30" constant with a correct value.

Is there any way to measure Hyperlinks' height in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to measure the fonts height  `Font.Height` then use this with the base location of the element to determine the height to place the tooltip